# lsb_release command not found

Tags: 12.04, apt, skype, command-line

I am new to ubuntu OS. I am trying to install skype on ubuntu 12.04. I am following a tutorial that says

```
sudo apt-add-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner”
```

but when i execute this command, it says:

```
lsb_release-sc: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this step manually. Use the **Ubuntu Software Center** and look for Skype.

You will have a button to use the partner source (Use Source). And then you can click to install Skype.

[image]

No command line is required.

Comment: Yes installed it from software update center. Thanks :)

Comment: This might be a solution for skype, but it is not a solution for the question "lsb release not found" please remove this as the accepted answer

Comment: @JamesDunmore Sorry but the question was about Skype installation which resulted in the error lsb_release not found. So this is the response to the problem. Perhaps the question could be improved so it is clearer.

Comment: @Huygens sorry yes, I didn't mean to say that your answer wasn't helpful. Perhaps updating the thread title to be skype related - lots of people, including myself landed here because the thread title is "lsb_release command not found" and this chosen answer doesn't actually fix that. I know, I'm being pedantic - your answer is perfect for solving his problem :)

Answer (score 25):

Some reason you're missing that executable. I have it on mine and according to `dpkg -S`, it is part of the lsb-release package.

```
ned@flanders:~$ dpkg -S `which lsb_release`
lsb-release: /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

What does your system say about that package?

```
ned@flanders:~$ apt-cache policy lsb-release    
lsb-release:
  Installed: 4.0-0ubuntu20.3
  Candidate: 4.0-0ubuntu20.3
  Version table:
 *** 4.0-0ubuntu20.3 0
        500 http://ftp.utexas.edu/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.0-0ubuntu20 0
        500 http://ftp.utexas.edu/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
ned@flanders:~$
```

You can install with `sudo apt-get install lsb-release` provided your apt sources are correct.

Answer (score 10):

> sudo apt-add-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner”
>
> lsb_release-sc: command not found

I suspect that you simply forgot to put a whitespace between the command (`lsb_release`) and its options/switches (`-sc`).

Comment: :-) Please, take care to put ALL spaces. They are important.

Comment: His command does not work (with spaces) on my PC, so I suspect other issues ..

Comment: now the command not found problem is finished but now it gives
error: 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/precisepartner' invalid :-(

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution:

You are using the non-std **apt-add-** (should not matter), but are also using Windows-type unique characters for '**open-quote**' and '**close quote**'.

Try this instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```